# Multi-commodity Flow

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, max-flow

I have just been working on chapters of questions from the DPV textbook for my exam preparation. For one of them, I'm having some trouble but I have made some progress:

---

[image: DPV 7.20]

---

My solution:

I will be using linear programming to maximize x where
SUM {flow_i(s_i, v) for all i where v are nodes connecting to source s_i} >= x * d_i

subject to the constraints

- for each edge e , f1+..fk <= c_e
- for each edge e, flow_e >= 0
- and some more constraints that I'm unsure of

I think I'm on the right track but I need some help getting a bit further. Should I be considering trying to use a super-node to reduce this to a regular max flow problem?

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one typical approach to multi-source, multi-sink commodity flow problems is to introduce a *super-source* and one *super-sink*. Then connect all the sources *s1...sk* to the super-source. Connect each sink *t1,...tk* to the super-sink.

**Important**: Give a very large capacity to all the edges leaving or entering any of the super-nodes.

**Objective**: Maximize the total throughoput. (Sum of flows over all edges leaving the sources 1..k)

#### Constraints:

*Edge Capacity Constraints:*

You already got this right.

- for each edge e , f1+..fk <= c_e

*Flow Conservation (Flow-in == Flow_out):*

- for each vertex v, sum of flow into v = sum of flow leaving v

*Demand Satisfaction:*

- for each sink t_i, sum of flow into t_i (all edges ending in t_i) >= demand_i

Non-zero flows, which you already have.

Here's [one accessible lecture handout](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs261/lecture16.pdf) that references your specific problem. Specifically, take a look at Example 2 in the handout.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, Ram. I've looked at the Stanford lecture and it seems very thorough. I'll go through his other examples too for extra preparation. Again, thank you!